# Immutable value of Array only has mutating members named append

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6, syntax-error

This error pops up :

> Immutable value of [PrizeItem] only has mutating members named append on the code line : prizesList.append(randomPrize)

```
 func openPrizeBox(){

        let prizeCycleCount = randomNumberInRange(8, 20) //<-Returns random Int
        let timeInterval = NSTimeInterval(prizeCycleCount)

        let prizesList : [PrizeItem] = []

        for var i = 0; i < prizeCycleCount; i++  {
            let randomPrize = prizeItems[randomNumberInRange(0, prizeItems.count-1)]
            prizesList.append(randomPrize) //Shows error here
        }
```

This is the PrizeItem Struct

```
struct PrizeItem {

enum Rank {
    case Ok
    case Good
    case Epic
    case Rare
    case ExtremelyRare
}

var name : String
var description : String

let rank : Rank


var identifier: String

}
```

Array:

```
let prizeItems : [PrizeItem] = [

PrizeItem(name: "Laser", description: "Test Item", rank: PrizeItem.Rank.Good, identifier: "laser")

]
```

If you can help me that would be great!
Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Did you read about `let` vs `var` in the Swift book?

Comment: @MartinR What do i need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use **let** you cannot change or append or add new things to this variable.Therefore in this line :

```
let prizesList : [PrizeItem] = []
```

should be change to

```
var prizesList : [PrizeItem] = []
```

**Important Using let only when you need to this value to be constant**

Comment: Thanks! You made my day. That was a stupid mistake. XD  I spent a long hour removing and editing code. Thanks for your help!